# How do I resolve the error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:5"

Tags: java, arrays

I'm completely new to programming and Java will be my first language. I'm using eclipse for all of my coding as well.

I've been looking into arrays just trying to understand them. I found this site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

I made my own variation of their first code example:

```
package testArray;

public class TestArray
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     // Declare a new array of integers
     int[] anArray;

     // Sets the array length to 5
     anArray = new int[5];

     // Setting each array element
     anArray[0] = 1;
     anArray[1] = 2;
     anArray[2] = 3;
     anArray[3] = 4;
     anArray[5] = 5;

     // Displaying the value of each array element
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[0]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[1]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[2]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[3]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[4]);

  }
}
```

I keep getting this error in the console:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at testArray.TestArray.main(TestArray.java:15)

I've tried using the code from their site as well but receive the same error. Is something not setup in eclipse right?

Any help is much appreciated!

Note: If anyone has some helpful sites that would be useful to a beginning programmer, go ahead and add them with your post!

Comment: Arrays are *zero indexed* in almost all programming languages.

Comment: @BrianRoach Except Lua, just for completeness' sake.

Comment: @hexafraction - And a couple others, but the concept shouldn't be foreign, and covered by any Java book or tutorial (including the one the OP linked to) .

Comment: Try reading your tutorial more closely. As the 2nd paragraph from your link states: "_numbering begins at zero..._"

Comment: I think it's kind of harsh that new programmers get down voted for making minor errors (in most cases) which could be easily and kindly pointed out.

Comment: @JoshM "harsh" is subjective. There are a thousand forums / sites on the net to post "I don't understand the basics of programming, can't read documentation, and am getting an error that I'm incapable of doing a google search for". The stated purpose of SO is *not* to be one of those sites. (And yeah, that's kinda "harsh" :) )

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem:

```
 anArray[5] = 5;
```

replace this by:

```
 anArray[4] = 5;
```

as yo have defined an array of size 5, so you can only use index between 0-4:

```
 anArray = new int[5];
```

If you try to access any index above 4, you will run into ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Oh I don't even know how I missed that! Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

```
anArray[5] = 5;
```

actually accesses the 6th element which doesn't exist as arrays are 0-based. `new int[5]` contains 5 elements, numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

all indices should be less than the array length. Use `anArray[4] = 5;` instead.

Comment: @badchiefy No problem. Please tickmark/checkmark the answer that helped, in this case likely that of Juned Ahsan.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java are 0 based and you have created an array of size 5.

anArray[5] = 5; is outside the bounds of your array but it looks like it might just be a typo.

You probably meant to put

anArray[4] = 5;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want

```
package testArray;

public class TestArray
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     // Declare a new array of integers
     int[] anArray;

     // Sets the array length to 5
     anArray = new int[5];

     // Setting each array element
     anArray[0] = 1;
     anArray[1] = 2;
     anArray[2] = 3;
     anArray[3] = 4;
     anArray[4] = 5;

     // Displaying the value of each array element
     System.out.println("Element at index 0: " + anArray[0]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 1: " + anArray[1]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 2: " + anArray[2]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 3: " + anArray[3]);
     System.out.println("Element at index 4: " + anArray[4]);

  }
}
```